# Insert multiple records from joining temporary tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to insert multiple return records from a joining select command to a temporary table. I used the below command . The select statement return two value but when i insert using the below command then the (`#TempTableValue`) temporary table have nothing.All other field declaration is ok and the joining select command is returning value properly.

```
INSERT into #TempTableValue DEFAULT values
SELECT #temp1.id,#temp1.DestFieldName,#temp2.FieldValues 
FROM #temp2
INNER JOIN #temp1
ON #temp2.FieldName=#temp1.SourceFieldName

select * from #TempTableValue
```

But the last select command return all Null value. What is the problem here?

Comment: could  you please provide the create statement for #TempTableValue table? I would like to see what are the default values you set for the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `DEFAULT value` as below:

```
INSERT into #TempTableValue 
SELECT #temp1.id,#temp1.DestFieldName,#temp2.FieldValues 
FROM #temp2
INNER JOIN #temp1 ON #temp2.FieldName=#temp1.SourceFieldName
```

from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

> DEFAULT VALUES
>
> Forces the new row to contain the default values defined for each
>   column.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I think I know what's wrong here.
If you use Insert Into #TempTableValue You have to **First Create the temp table**.
To **directly insert** your Selection you could use this

```
Select #temp1.id,#temp1.DestFieldName,#temp2.FieldValues Into #TempTableValue
FROM #temp2
INNER JOIN #temp1
ON #temp2.FieldName=#temp1.SourceFieldName
```